# How to get System.PullRequest.TargetBranch using azure devops piplines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to set root scope variable to keep context of execution like this:

```
variables:
    ${{ if  and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')) }}:
      isMainPr: true
    ${{ else }}: 
      isMainPr: false
    ${{ if and( eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/')) }}:
      isReleasePr: true
    ${{ else }}: 
      isReleasePr: false
    aaa: ${{ variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'] }}
    bbb: ${{ variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'] }}
```

Then I can execute the echo task:

```
stages:    
- stage: CI   
  jobs:   
  - job: Echo
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Echo
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "CI"
          Write-Host "aaa:" ${{ variables.aaa }}
          Write-Host "bbb:" ${{ variables.bbb }}
          Write-Host "Build.Reason" $(Build.Reason)
          Write-Host "SourceBranch:" $(Build.SourceBranch)
          Write-Host "isMainPr:" ${{ variables.isMainPr }}
          Write-Host "isReleasePr:" ${{ variables.isReleasePr }}
          Write-Host "System.PullRequest.TargetBranch:" $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
```

With the output:

```
CI
aaa:
bbb:
Build.Reason PullRequest
SourceBranch: refs/pull/32542/merge
isMainPr: false
isReleasePr: false
System.PullRequest.TargetBranch: refs/heads/main
```

The issue is that *System.PullRequest.TargetBranch* is not 'visible' on root variables level.
I want to achieve sth like this:

```
- stage: MAIN_PR
  condition: and(succeeded(),eq ( ${{ variables.isMainPr }}, True ))
  dependsOn:
  - CI
```

The **root** scope variable/param that is set and then applied consume on stages.
I know I can on each stage build complex conditions, but I want to avoid it.
Any solutions or proposition of your projects are valid. Maybe I approach this problem wrongly.

The repo structure:
'main' branch with pr from

- features/*
- bugs/*

'releases/*' branches with pr from

- hotfix/*

Comment: To explain what is happening, it seems like initially `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` is undefined and it gets defined at runtime. That's why the compile time expressions return empty results, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax). However I have no idea how to fix your use case.